# Find all $n$ such that $\phi \left(n\right)=36$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\phi \left(n\right)=36$

This list of primes that can occur is $\{2,3,5,7,11,13,19,37\}$

Knowing this how can I find all such numbers, is brute force too slow here?

Comment: If prime $p$ divides $n,p-1$  must divide $\phi(n)$

Comment: does that mean that I can disregard 5,7,13,19?

Comment: No, because $(5-1)|36$, for example.

Comment: $11$ shouldn't be on your list.

Comment: But how can I find such numbers I know that 37 is one, would it work if I find all $\phi$ that are 4 and 9 instread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  You can factor $36=2^23^2$ to guide your search.  None of the primes in your list except $2,3$ can appear more than once as they do not divide into $36$ and if you had a factor $p^2$ in $n$ you would have a factor $p(p-1)$ in $\phi(n)$.  I would start from the top.  If $n=37, \phi(n)=36$ and we have one.  If $m=19$ is a factor, $\phi(m)=18$ and we need another factor of $2$.  How can you get that?  I see two ways.  Keep going.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot!

Comment: For 19 we have 3,4,6 thus 57,76,114

For 13 we have nothing.

For 7 we have 9,14 and so on.. great answer!

Comment: Yes, that is right.  I overlooked $6$.